# nuget package is available but contains empty methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget

I have created a dotnet core package. Packed it and pushed to NuGet feed. The nupkg file is available in the nuget feed and discoverable:
[image]
The reference is correctly linked in the solution:
[image]

However all the methods are empty. Why it's like that?
[image]

Comment: You're using Visual Studio to view the methods available in a package that's been referenced? It just shows the method signatures and not the bodies: that's expected. (The exact detail of your methods, such as formatting, variable names, comments, etc, were lost when your DLL was compiled. There are tools which can do a reasonable job at reconstructing the C# code from the compiled DLL, but VS doesn't do this by default)

Comment: There's a guide on NuGet on how to include source files for reference browsing, I'll suggest you to follow it

Comment: You could also add the DLL manually that you created and see if it works as you expect it too. There should be no difference. You could even in fact take the DLL from the Nuget package.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'm new to C# world and would appreciate any help regarding the tools i can use to compile it properly

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink

Comment: Thank you, Camilo. Appreciate it

Comment: @DenisS. I think everything is fine. Camilo's link is about making it easier to debug method calls which go into your nuget package: if you don't need to do that, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, @canton7. I'm trying to run my tests locally at the moment but no luck. Is there a way  to reconstructing the C# code from the compiled DLL?

Comment: You can grab a tool like dotPeek / de4dot / others. I think it would be worth opening another question about the specific problems you're having: I can't offer any advice based on the little information you've given, and my guess is that you're suspecting the wrong things: i.e. an XY problem

Comment: Your app *did* compile properly. The fact that you're not seeing the method implementations is not an indication of a problem. If you want to see the source, then go back to your original source code that you used to build the nupkg, or follow Camilo's suggestion for wiring it up for reference browsing. So you're probably barking up the wrong tree - what's the actual problem that you're trying to fix? Is some code not functioning as you expected it to?

Comment: Thanks @mason for the note. Fortunately i switched to rider from jetbrains, the resharper  helped me out with to have access to the content of all methods from my package.

Comment: That's likely not the actual content. That's just decompiling the DLL, so it won't give you the actual original source. For example, it's probably a bit different in syntax and lacking the comments. If you want the real source, follow Camilo's suggestion or just go pull up the source in your source control.

Comment: @mason, sorry for the silly question: how to pull up the source in my source control in visual studio?

Comment: Just like you'd pull up the source control for any other repository you have. You're using Git?

Comment: yep, i'm using git